# What is the best way to invite multiple friends for using an app?

Tags: facebook

We are building an app. On our app you can send an app link to your friends, we want to send this as a personal message. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the facebook JS SDK it's actually pretty easy to use the Facbeook Request Dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Below is some code I've used in the past:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    channelUrl : 'http://www.yoursite.com/channel.php',
    appId: 'yourfacebookappid',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
  });

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      title: 'Select Friends To Invite',
      message: 'Join me in playing this app!'
    }, inviteCallback);
  }

  function inviteCallback(response) {
    if (response==undefined) {
      // user didn't invite anyone
    } else {
      // user invited someone
    }
  }
</script>
```

Basically once you get the Javascript SDK into your app, you just need to call the sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector function with a link or some action on your page and the request dialog will popup. Then you can handle the callback in another function and it'll determine if the user invited someone or not so you can show them additional copy if you'd like.